# Dynamic Configuration in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was creating a directive to display a chart.
I went through the usual templates of creating a module, with a directive. For configuration, I decided to use a Provider.
I understood how I could have the application set up my module's configuration through the provider.

However, one use case that I have is that the configuration can change based on the user's preferences at run-time.
How do I enable my module to provide a way for the client API to modify the configuration at run-time?

Is it possible to inject the ProviderConfiguration into the Client's Controller as well? Are their any significant drawbacks to this approach?

The current code template looks like this

```
//Provider
angular.module('foobar', []).provider('foobarConfig', [function() {
    var config = {
        //config properties here.
    }
    var configurationProvider = {
        //Getters and Setters that work on 'config'.
        setProperty(prop, value) {
            if(config[prop] !== undefined) {
                config[prop] = value;
            }
        },
        getProperty(prop) {
            return config[prop];
        },
        $get: function() {
            return this;
        }
    }
    return configurationProvider;
}

//Chart Directive.
angular.module('foobar').directive('foobarChart', ['foobarConfig', function(foobarConfig) {
    //Can use the foobarConfig here.
}]);

angular.module('clientApp', [ 'foobar'])
.config(['foobarConfigProvider', function(foobarConfigProvider) {
    //Can provide the initial configuration to the module here.
    foobarConfigProvider.setProperty("foo", "bar");
}]);

angular.module('clientApp').directive('clientFoo', function() {

    //What should be done to change foobarConfig here?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly valid recipe for configuration service which is available in both config and run phases, so `foobarConfigProvider.setProperty("foo", "bar")` and `foobarConfig.setProperty("foo", "bar")` can be used in the same way.

For the configuration service which doesn't have dependencies `constant` is even more convenient alternative:

```
.constant('foobarConfig', (function () {
    var config = {
        // ...
    };

    return {
        setProperty: function (prop, value) {
            if(config[prop] !== undefined) {
                config[prop] = value;
            }
        },
        getProperty: function (prop) {
            return config[prop];
        }
    };
})());
```

For ES5-compatible solution with limited set of configuration keys, `constant` object with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) may be used, this eliminates the need for custom getter/setter functions. `Object.defineProperty` may be iterated over initial `config` object, so no boilerplate descriptor code is required:

```
.constant('foobarConfig', (function () {
    var config = {
        // ...
    };

    var obj = {};

    angular.forEach(config, function (value, key) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            enumerable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: value
            // no 'get' and 'set' are required if the only purpose for
            // them is to restrict a set of config keys
        })
    });

    Object.seal(obj);

    return obj;
})());
```

Notice that the main difference (and possible drawback) for `constant` here is that service value is being eagerly defined, `foobarConfig` will be the same object for different injectors. Usually there is no difference for production, but this may (or may not) affect testing.

Comment: Thanks for the bit about using `constant` alternative.